# Trying to display user meta by "name" - not by "ID"

Tags: php, users, forms

I have a form on my website where users can submit their own posts and one of the fields has a dropdown containing various countries so a user can enter their location. I would like this location to be displayed when the post is published so I have written the below code to achieve this:

```
<?php echo stripslashes(get_user_meta($uid, 'user_location', true)); ?>
```

However, this only displays the category "ID" number (not the category "name" of the location). What can I write so the NAME of the location is displayed?

Comment: Is there an easy way to display the LOCATION BY NAME (rather than ID NUMBER)? I have included the code that was used for the page where the form is:

<?php   

$locs = get_user_meta($uid, 'user_location', true);

echo PricerrTheme_get_categories("job_location",  
        !isset($_POST['job_location_cat']) ?  $locs : htmlspecialchars($_POST['job_location_cat'])
        , __('Select Location','PricerrTheme'), "do_input"); ?>

        </p>

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category) to convert the ID into a category data object.

```
$cid = get_user_meta($uid, 'user_location', true);
$c = get_category($cid);
echo $c->name;
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. If it helps, the taxonomy = "job_location" when I hover over the category name. And "job_location_cat" is also mentioned in the code.

Comment: You called this a "category" but you may need `get_term()` instead.